# how to user over partition by in case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.1, window-functions

The below are the results from a select statement

```
   u_id | l_id | risk      | Count | Avg
----------------------------------------
|   1   |  10  |Critical   |  3    | 33.33
|   1   |  10  |Limited    |  3    | 33.33
|   1   |  10  |Medium     |  2    | 22.22
|   1   |  10  |Significant|  1    | 11.11
|   2   |  9   |Medium     |  1    | 50.00
|   2   |  9   |Significant|  1    | 50.00
|   3   |  8   |Limited    |  1    | 50.00
|   3   |  8   |Medium     |  1    | 50.00
```

I used a case statement to get results from the select statement but I want to get results making u_id and l_id as unique.

case statement:

```
SELECT u_id, l_id, (CASE WHEN risk = 'Critical' THEN 'Critical'
         WHEN risk = 'Significant' AND avg >= 50 THEN 'Critical'
         WHEN risk = 'Significant' AND risk <> 'Critical' THEN 'Significant'
         WHEN risk = 'Medium' AND avg >= 50 THEN 'Medium'
         ELSE 'Limited' -- OVER (PARTITION BY u_id,l_id) 
         END) as crr 
         From
             ( select ...(select ... ) a .. ) b
```

actual results

```
  u_id | l_id | risk      
--------------------------
|   1   |  10  |Critical   
|   1   |  10  |Limited    
|   1   |  10  |Limited    
|   1   |  10  |Significant
|   2   |  9   |Medium     
|   2   |  9   |Critical   
|   3   |  8   |Limited    
|   3   |  8   |Medium
```

what I am expecting is

```
   u_id | l_id | risk      
--------------------------
|   1   |  10  |Critical   
|   2   |  9   |Critical  
|   3   |  8   |Medium
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has a nice syntax for this:  `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u_id, l_id) u_id, l_id,
       (CASE WHEN risk = 'Critical' THEN 'Critical'
             WHEN risk = 'Significant' AND avg >= 50 THEN 'Critical'
             WHEN risk = 'Significant' AND risk <> 'Critical' THEN 'Significant'
             WHEN risk = 'Medium' AND avg >= 50 THEN 'Medium'
             ELSE 'Limited' -- OVER (PARTITION BY u_id,l_id) 
        END) as crr 
FROM ( select ...(select ... ) a .. ) b 
ORDER BY u_id, l_id, ??;
```

The key here is the `ORDER BY`.  I'm guessing you want the highest risk.  One method is:

```
ORDER BY u_id, l_id,
          (case when risk = 'Critical' then 1
           . . .
          )
```

Comment: Many thanks @Gordon, by adding "DISTINCT ON (u_id, l_id) u_id, l_id,", It's working.